# How to use the function market.api.process of Rbitcoin in R?

Tags: php, r, protocols

Using the package "Rbitcoin", I am trying to download bid/ask quotations:

```
ticker <- market.api.process(market = 'bitstamp', currency_pair = c('BTC', 'USD'), action='ticker')
```

And I receive this error:

> Error: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version

I am using R 3.6.1.